# Restricted access issue: unable to run a code workbook script to produce a dataset

Tags: palantir-foundry

After previously being able to run code workbook scripts, the run button has now been 'greyed out' with a permissions restriction message saying 'No permission to run in output folder' when I hover over the button.
Does anyone know why this has occurred and how to recover permissions to run?
[image: Run button greyed out]

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the output dataset that this step in the workbook produces has been moved to a different location (probably a different project) where you don't have write access.

Try viewing the dataset in Compass (the file browser). This might tell you who has most recently edited it, which could help you find the right person to ask why it was moved. You might not be able to do this if you don't still have discoverer access on the output dataset.

Alternatively, ask your permission administrator or IT team for access to the project it has been moved to / for it to be moved back.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
What you say does make sense, however, it looks like noone has moved the output folders/datasets in the project and I can't see why someone would've edited my permissions.
I've managed to rebuild the dataset (via the code workbook) through using the 'build' button on the dataset, however, i'm not able to from the workbook itself. I'm trying to work out how to send a another image here to display that...

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. Unfortunately I'm not sure what else could cause that error. It might be best to raise an issue to your Palantir support team, probably via the 'Issues' app. Answering your own question later if it is something others can learn from might be helpful in that case.